# Wifi Dongle MT7601U connection issue

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, internet

Wifi dongle connects, but the internet is unstable. Sometimes it's really good but seconds after, it stops or became really slow. Then a minute after, it returns to normal.
It happens with two different wifi routers I tried, but it doesn't happen when I'm using my mobile phone as a router.
I'm using Ubuntu 18.04.4 with kernel 4.15.0-108-generic.
There is an anormal amount of excessive retries and invalid misc showing on iwconfig.

**iwconfig:**

```
wlx20e6170547f3  IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"IV2"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.462 GHz  Access Point: 00:1A:3F:8C:EF:DC   
          Bit Rate=54 Mb/s   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=69/70  Signal level=-41 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:2162  Invalid misc:15348   Missed beacon:0
```

**ifconfigf:**

```
wlx20e6170547f3: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.0.0.117  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.0.0.255
        inet6 fe80::e14f:6814:691f:ae65  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 20:e6:17:05:47:f3  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 1597397  bytes 1916774385 (1.9 GB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 953376  bytes 114675969 (114.6 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

**sudo lshw -C network:**

```
*-network
       description: Wireless interface
       physical id: 3
       bus info: usb@1:1.2
       logic name: wlx20e6170547f3
       serial: 20:e6:17:05:47:f3
       capacity: ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=mt7601u driverversion=4.15.0-108-generic firmware=N/A ip=10.0.0.117 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
```